# Creating road/streets and adding numbering on street in relation to the plots. ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I am trying to connect through a geodatabase all the streets with their numbers and the houses. So far I created a feature class for streets, one for points and one for polygons which both represent the plots.

But I can't find a way to add in the data base the numbering of each street on both sides, left and right.

My final goal on this report is for example when there is damage on the water network underneath the road on a specific point it will return the exact address of this point.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: You should embed images in your question rather than posting a link. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post Also, SE doesn't support HTML markup in posts.

Comment: Also related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62998/assigning-centerline-address-ranges

Answer (score 2):

For a line feature class for streets you can only use geocoding ranges, and the point along the street will be only an approximate address based on an interpolation of the house number between the range end points, rarely an exact address (unless you are lucky).  That is because houses never are distributed exactly spaced at the same distance on every portion of a road segment.  An exact address geocoder can be created from your points, which works well if you are directly searching for an exact address or reverse geocoding from an exact address, but to correlate the points of failure on a road that have no address to an address on the road they are associated with the interpolated ranges from the street will generally work best.

For the geocoding house number ranges you need four fields (they can be Long or String whole numbers) with the names representing:

From Left House Number

To Left House Number

From Right House Number

To Right House Number

The house ranges are assigned based on the orientation of the street line segment, so that if even house numbers are on the left of the line and odd house numbers are on the right of the line and the house numbers increase in the direction of the line then the ranges would be something like:

From_Left_House = 1000

To_Left_House = 1998

From_Right+House = 1001

To_Right_House = 1999

Most people manually assign all of the ranges.  There is no easy way to automate the assignment of these number ranges based on your house points or polygons.  However, I have posted one method of using points to assign the ranges in [this blog post](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/08/29/assigning-address-ranges-based-on-existing-address-points).  You will see that it is a complex task with a lot of steps and validations required.

Comment: For the maintenance of house number ranges when roads split you can use the Address Data Management AddIn, which has tools to help manage splitting the ranges and flipping the ranges.  Splits of the ranges only work if the lines are oriented in the direction that the range increases.  If the line is oriented with the numbers as they decrease, the line split tool incorrectly proportions the numbers as though they were increasing when you split them.  Press the Open button at this url to download it: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6f3990ee91f14d45b62379a3e74a9c41

Comment: Updated link 
http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/address-management/

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't comfortable guesstimating based on the building addresses on the street, try looking in the local county or municipality geoportal for some sort of grid of address ranges. For example, the image below is a screenshot of the address grid of points from Pima County.

[image: Pima County Address Points]